# JTextArea disable scroll on select all

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

**Alert:** we were wrong in closing this, please vote to re-open so can get a proper answer!

Every time I select all (Ctrl+A) text on a text area, it scrolls to the bottom.

Is there anyway to maintain the position or the visible rectangle while still selecting all the contents?

**UPDATE**

This is not a duplicate of [Java / Swing : JTextArea in a JScrollPane, how to prevent auto-scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972337/java-swing-jtextarea-in-a-jscrollpane-how-to-prevent-auto-scroll) since in here, the text in the textarea is not updated but just selected (i.e. select all).

**Update Kleopatra**

(not exactly up to netiquette, but you need an answer asap, I assume - so I add it here until the question is re-opened, then move :-)

What you basically need is a custom caret, I don't know if that's the whole story, though, as NavigationFilters might (or not) get into the way: in that caret, override adjustVisibilty to conditionally scroll or not to the new dot. A sample:

```
public static class MyCaret extends DefaultCaret {

    @Override
    protected void adjustVisibility(Rectangle nloc) {
        if (ignoreAdjustVisibility()) {
            return;
        }
        super.adjustVisibility(nloc);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a boolean to indicate whether to scroll the dot to visible.
     * This implementation checks for all-selected, that is mark at the start
     * and dot at the end.
     * @return
     */
    private boolean ignoreAdjustVisibility() {
        return (getMark() == 0) && 
                (getDot() == getComponent().getDocument().getLength());
    }

}

// use in application code
JTextArea text = new JTextArea(10, 20);
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) text.getCaret();
MyCaret myCaret = new MyCaret();
// for some reason, the blinkrate isn't installed correctly, so do it manually
myCaret.setBlinkRate(caret.getBlinkRate());
text.setCaret(myCaret);
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks kleopatra. You're solution works. Hope this question will be reopened.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of Java / Swing : JTextArea in a JScrollPane, how to prevent auto-scroll? since in here, the text in the textarea is not updated but just selected (i.e. select all).

Comment: you are right - and we were wrong :-) The updatePolicy exclusively affects the scrolling after document modifications. Voted to re-open.

Comment: @trashgod trying to nudge you into voting for re-opening :-)

Comment: @StanislavL trying to nudge you into voting for re-opening :-)

Comment: @oers trying to nudge you into voting for re-opening :-)

Comment: @bažmegakapa trying to nudge you into voting for re-opening :-)