# How to disable scrollbar of Jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jscrollbar

How to Disable automatic scrolling of JtextArea.

```
JtextArea1.setColumns (100);
JtextArea1.setLineWrap (true);
JtextArea1.setWrapStyleWord (false);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textArea.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
```

Found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3973103/1515052)

Comment: +1 but I think this is default value, something wrong in OPs whatever

Comment: Thanks all for quick reply